EEVEE Emission is white and I need it in color
When I was following a quick tutorial in a sunstet the sphere was colored in orange yellow while mine has been in a constant white-orange.
I understand that the version in the tutorial is 2.8 but I was hoping there is a way to replicate the effect in the recent versions.
I'm using 4.1. Note. The only modifier used is Emission and thats it.



Are you using regular EEVEE, EEVEE-next or Cycles to render? The expected-outcome image looks like regular EEVEE without bloom enabled, which is what most emissive colors look like by default. If you are using EEVEE-regular then go to your render settings and make sure that bloom is turned off. All else failing, try turning down the emissive strength in the shader.

@Jakemoyo To me this simply looks like the older one uses View Transform > Standard in the Color Management, while the new one uses AgX instead. But just a guess without seeing any settings.

@GordonBrinkmann Yeah, There's a handful of render settings it could be. Definitely doesn't have anything to do with a modifier.

@GordonBrinkmann Yes this is it, I changed the Color Management > View Transform to Standard and its more colorful, thank you for the answer.

Thanks to @GordonBrinkmann, he solved it, by changing the View Transform to Standard in the Color Management I was able to get the result I was looking for.

